ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (tensorlow)
I am having an issue with tensor in tensorflow.
First is the code for the model.
class RepresentationsPathology():
def init(self...)
# Self-supervised inputs.
def model_inputs(self):

    # Image input for transformation.
    real_images_1 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, self.image_width, self.image_height, self.image_channels), name='real_images_1')
    real_images_2 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, self.image_width, self.image_height, self.image_channels), name='real_images_2')
    # Transformed images.
    transf_real_images_1 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.image_width, self.image_height, self.image_channels), name='transf_real_images_1')
    transf_real_images_2 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.image_width, self.image_height, self.image_channels), name='transf_real_images_2')

    # Learning rates.
    learning_rate_e = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='learning_rate_e')

    return real_images_1, real_images_2, transf_real_images_1, transf_real_images_2, learning_rate_e

# Data Augmentation Layer.
def data_augmentation_layer(self, images, crop, rotation, flip, g_blur, g_noise, color_distort, sobel_filter):
    images_trans = images

    # Spatial transformations.
    if crop:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_crop_and_resize_p075, images_trans)
    if rotation:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_rotate, images_trans)
    if flip:
        images_trans = random_flip(images_trans)

    # Gaussian blur and noise transformations.
    if g_blur:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_blur, images_trans)
    if g_noise:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_gaussian_noise, images_trans)

    # Color distorsions.
    if color_distort:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_color_jitter_1p0, images_trans)
    else:
        images_trans = tf_wrapper_rb_stain(images_trans)

    # Sobel filter.
    if sobel_filter:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_sobel_filter, images_trans)

    # Make sure the image batch is in the right format.
    images_trans = tf.reshape(images_trans, [-1, self.image_height, self.image_width, self.image_channels])
    images_trans = tf.clip_by_value(images_trans, 0., 1.)

    return images_trans


# Encoder Network.
def encoder(self, images, is_train, reuse, init, name, label_input=None):
    if '_0' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_1' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_1(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_2' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_2(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_3' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_3(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_4' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_4(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_5' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_5(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_6' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_6(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    elif '_7' in self.model_name:
        conv_space, h, z = encoder_resnet_contrastive_7(images=images, z_dim=self.z_dim, h_dim=1024, layers=self.layers, spectral=self.spectral, activation=ReLU, reuse=reuse, init=init,
                                                         is_train=is_train, normalization=batch_norm, regularizer=None, attention=self.attention, name=name)
    return conv_space, h, z

# Loss Function.
def loss(self, rep_t1, rep_t2):
    loss = cross_correlation_loss(z_a=rep_t1, z_b=rep_t2, lambda_=self.lambda_)
    return loss

# Optimizer.
def optimization(self):
    with tf.control_dependencies(tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
        # Learning rate decay.
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        self.lr_decayed_fn = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(self.learning_rate_input_e, decay_steps=3*self.num_samples, end_learning_rate=0.1*self.learning_rate_input_e,
                                                       power=0.5)
        #  Optimizer
        opt = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate_input_e, beta1=self.beta_1)
        # Quick dirty optimizer for Encoder.
        trainable_variables = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
        encoder_variables = [variable for variable in trainable_variables if variable.name.startswith('contrastive_encoder')]
        train_encoder = opt.minimize(self.loss_contrastive, var_list=encoder_variables)
    return train_encoder

# Build the Self-supervised.
def build_model(self):

    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    avail_gpus = [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']

    #INPUTS & DATA AUGMENTATION 
    # Inputs.


    self.real_images_1, self.real_images_2, self.transf_real_images_1, self.transf_real_images_2, self.learning_rate_input_e = self.model_inputs()
    # Data augmentation layer.

    print('real_images_1', self.real_images_1.shape)
    self.real_images_1_t1 = self.data_augmentation_layer(images=self.real_images_1, crop=self.crop, rotation=self.rotation, flip=self.flip, g_blur=self.g_blur, g_noise=self.g_noise,
                                                         color_distort=self.color_distort, sobel_filter=self.sobel_filter)
    print('real_images_t1', self.real_images_1_t1.shape)

    self.real_images_1_t2 = self.data_augmentation_layer(images=self.real_images_1, crop=self.crop, rotation=self.rotation, flip=self.flip, g_blur=self.g_blur, g_noise=self.g_noise,
                                                         color_distort=self.color_distort, sobel_filter=self.sobel_filter)
    print('real_images_t2', self.real_images_1_t2.shape)
    ################### TRAINING 
    # Encoder Training.
    self.conv_space_t1, self.h_rep_t1, self.z_rep_t1 = self.encoder(images=self.transf_real_images_1, is_train=True, reuse=False, init=self.init, name='contrastive_encoder')
    self.conv_space_t2, self.h_rep_t2, self.z_rep_t2 = self.encoder(images=self.transf_real_images_2, is_train=True, reuse=True,  init=self.init, name='contrastive_encoder')

    ################### INFERENCE 
    # Encoder Representations Inference.
    self.conv_space_out, self.h_rep_out, self.z_rep_out = self.encoder(images=self.real_images_2, is_train=False, reuse=True, init=self.init, name='contrastive_encoder')

    ################### LOSS & OPTIMIZER 
    # Losses.
    self.loss_contrastive = self.loss(rep_t1=self.z_rep_t1, rep_t2=self.z_rep_t2)
    # Optimizers.
    self.train_encoder  = self.optimization()

def project_subsample(self, session, data, epoch, data_out_path, report, batch_size=50):
    # Updated
    if not report:
        return

    # Handle directories and copies.
    results_path = os.path.join(data_out_path, 'results')
    epoch_path = os.path.join(results_path, 'epoch_%s' % epoch)
    check_epoch_path = os.path.join(epoch_path, 'checkpoints')
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(results_path, '../checkpoints')
    os.makedirs(epoch_path)
    shutil.copytree(checkpoint_path, check_epoch_path)

    num_samples = 10000

    # Setup HDF5 file.
    hdf5_path = os.path.join(epoch_path, 'hdf5_epoch_%s_projected_images.h5' % epoch)
    hdf5_file = h5py.File(hdf5_path, mode='w')
    img_storage  = hdf5_file.create_dataset(name='images',           shape=[num_samples, data.patch_h, data.patch_w, data.n_channels], dtype=np.float32)
    conv_storage = hdf5_file.create_dataset(name='conv_features',    shape=[num_samples] + self.conv_space_t1.shape.as_list()[1:],     dtype=np.float32)
    h_storage    = hdf5_file.create_dataset(name='h_representation', shape=[num_samples] + self.h_rep_t1.shape.as_list()[1:],          dtype=np.float32)
    z_storage    = hdf5_file.create_dataset(name='z_representation', shape=[num_samples] + self.z_rep_t1.shape.as_list()[1:],          dtype=np.float32)

    ind = 0
    while ind<num_samples:
        images_batch = data.training.images[self.selected_indx[ind: ind+batch_size], :, :, :]
        feed_dict = {self.real_images_2:images_batch}
        conv_space_out, h_rep_out, z_rep_out = session.run([self.conv_space_out, self.h_rep_out, self.z_rep_out], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        img_storage[ind: ind+batch_size, :, : ,:]  = images_batch
        conv_storage[ind: ind+batch_size, :] = conv_space_out
        h_storage[ind: ind+batch_size, :]    = h_rep_out
        z_storage[ind: ind+batch_size, :]    = z_rep_out
        ind += batch_size
    try:
        conv_path, label_conv_path = report_progress_latent(epoch=epoch, w_samples=conv_storage, img_samples=img_storage, img_path=hdf5_path.split('/hdf5')[0], storage_name='conv_lat', metric='euclidean')
        h_path   , label_h_path    = report_progress_latent(epoch=epoch, w_samples=h_storage,    img_samples=img_storage, img_path=hdf5_path.split('/hdf5')[0], storage_name='h_lat',    metric='euclidean')
        z_path   , label_z_path    = report_progress_latent(epoch=epoch, w_samples=z_storage,    img_samples=img_storage, img_path=hdf5_path.split('/hdf5')[0], storage_name='z_lat',    metric='euclidean')
        if self.wandb_flag:
            wandb.log({"Conv Space": wandb.Image(conv_path), "H Space":    wandb.Image(h_path), "Z Space":    wandb.Image(z_path)})
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Issue printing latent space images. Epoch', epoch)
        if hasattr(ex, 'message'):
            print('\t\tException', ex.message)
        else:
            print('\t\tException', ex)
    finally:
        os.remove(hdf5_path)


# Training function.
def train(self, epochs, data_out_path, data, restore, print_epochs=10, n_images=25, checkpoint_every=None, report=False):

    if self.wandb_flag:
        train_config = save_model_config(self, data)
        run_name = self.model_name + '-' + data.dataset
        wandb.init(project='SSL Pathology', entity='adalbertocquiros', name=run_name, config=train_config)

    run_epochs = 0
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()

    # Setups.
    checkpoints, csvs = setup_output(data_out_path=data_out_path, model_name=self.model_name, restore=restore)
    losses = ['Redundancy Reduction Loss Train', 'Redundancy Reduction Loss Validation']
    setup_csvs(csvs=csvs, model=self, losses=losses)
    report_parameters(self, epochs, restore, data_out_path)

    # Session Options.
    # config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    run_options = tf.compat.v1.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom=True)

    print('Starting run.')
    # Training session.
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) as session:
        if self.wandb_flag: wandb.tensorflow.log(tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all())
        session.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

        # Restore previous session.
        if restore:
            check = get_checkpoint(data_out_path)
            saver.restore(session, check)
            print('Restored model: %s' % check)

        # Example of augmentation images.
        batch_images, batch_labels = data.training.next_batch(n_images)

        lst = []
        for x in batch_images:
            x = x.reshape(512,512,3).astype(np.float32)
            lst.append(x)
        batch_images = np.array(lst)




        batch_images = np.reshape(batch_images, [-1, self.image_width, self.image_height, self.image_channels])

        data.training.reset()
        feed_dict = {self.real_images_1:batch_images, self.real_images_2:batch_images}
        output_layers_transformed = [self.real_images_1_t1, self.real_images_1_t2]

        transformed_images = session.run(output_layers_transformed, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)



        # Assuming you have already constructed your feed_dict


            # Iterate through the elements of the array



        transformed_images = session.run(output_layers_transformed, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
        write_sprite_image(filename=os.path.join(data_out_path, 'images/transformed_1.png'), data=transformed_images[0], metadata=False)
        write_sprite_image(filename=os.path.join(data_out_path, 'images/transformed_2.png'), data=transformed_images[1], metadata=False)
        if self.wandb_flag:
            dict_ = {"transformed_1": wandb.Image(os.path.join(data_out_path, 'images/transformed_1.png')), "transformed_2": wandb.Image(os.path.join(data_out_path, 'images/transformed_2.png'))}
            wandb.log(dict_)

        # Epoch Iteration.
        for epoch in range(0, epochs+1):

            # Batch Iteration.
            for batch_images, batch_labels in data.training:

                ##TRAINING ENCODER 
                # Update discriminator.
                print('feed_dict', feed_dict)
                feed_dict = {self.real_images_1:batch_images, self.real_images_2:batch_images}
                transformed_images = session.run(output_layers_transformed, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
                feed_dict = {self.transf_real_images_1:transformed_images[0], self.transf_real_images_2:transformed_images[1],
                             self.real_images_1:batch_images, self.real_images_2:batch_images, self.learning_rate_input_e: self.learning_rate_e}
                session.run([self.train_encoder], feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
                

                # Print losses and Generate samples.
                if run_epochs % print_epochs == 0:
                    model_outputs = [self.loss_contrastive]
                    epoch_outputs = session.run(model_outputs, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)

                    # Validation loss. 
                    for batch_images, batch_labels in data.validation:
                        feed_dict = {self.real_images_1:batch_images, self.real_images_2:batch_images}
                        output_layers_transformed = [self.real_images_1_t1, self.real_images_1_t2]
                        transformed_images = session.run(output_layers_transformed, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
                        feed_dict = {self.transf_real_images_1:transformed_images[0], self.transf_real_images_2:transformed_images[1], \
                                self.real_images_1:batch_images, self.real_images_2:batch_images, self.learning_rate_input_e: self.learning_rate_e}
                        val_outputs = session.run(model_outputs, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)

                        update_csv(model=self, file=csvs[0], variables=[epoch_outputs[0], val_outputs[0]], epoch=epoch, iteration=run_epochs, losses=losses)
                        if self.wandb_flag: wandb.log({'Redundancy Reduction Loss Train': epoch_outputs[0], 'Redundancy Reduction Loss Validation': val_outputs[0],})
                        break
                    
                run_epochs += 1
                if epoch==0: break

            # Save model.
            saver.save(sess=session, save_path=checkpoints)
            data.training.reset()

            ############################### FID TRACKING 
            # Save checkpoint and generate images for FID every X epochs.
            if (checkpoint_every is not None and epoch % checkpoint_every == 0) or (epochs==epoch):
                self.project_subsample(session=session, data=data, epoch=epoch, data_out_path=data_out_path, report=report)

    if self.wandb_flag:
        wandb.finish()









~~~`
# the augmentation is as such:
import ....

# Random sampling to recide if the transformation is applied.
def random_apply(func, p, x):
    return tf.cond(tf.less(tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(p, tf.float32)), lambda: func(x), lambda: x)


############### COLOR ###############
# Two version of random change to brightness: Addition/Multiplicative.
def random_brightness(image, max_delta, impl='simclrv2'):
    if impl == 'simclrv2':
        factor = tf.random.uniform([], tf.maximum(1.0 - max_delta, 0), 1.0 + max_delta)
        image = image * factor
    elif impl == 'simclrv1':    
        image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=max_delta)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown impl {} for random brightness.'.format(impl))
    return image

# Random color transformations: Bright, Contrast, Saturation, and Hue.
def color_jitter_rand(image, brightness=0, contrast=0, saturation=0, hue=0, impl='simclrv2'):
    with tf.name_scope('distort_color'):
        def apply_transform(i, x):
            def brightness_foo():
                if brightness == 0:
                    return x
                else:
                    return random_brightness(x, max_delta=brightness, impl=impl)
            def contrast_foo():
                if contrast == 0:
                    return x
                else:
                    return tf.image.random_contrast(x, lower=1-contrast, upper=1+contrast)
            def saturation_foo():
                if saturation == 0:
                    return x
                else:
                    return tf.image.random_saturation(x, lower=1-saturation, upper=1+saturation)
            def hue_foo():
                if hue == 0:
                    return x
                else:
                    return tf.image.random_hue(x, max_delta=hue)
            x = tf.cond(tf.less(i, 2),
                        lambda: tf.cond(tf.less(i, 1), brightness_foo, contrast_foo),
                        lambda: tf.cond(tf.less(i, 3), saturation_foo, hue_foo))
            return x

        perm = tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(4))
        for i in range(4):
            image = apply_transform(perm[i], image)
            image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0., 1.)
        return image

# No random color transformations: 1st Bright, 2nd Contrast, 3rd Saturation, and 4th Hue.
def color_jitter_nonrand(image, brightness=0, contrast=0, saturation=0, hue=0, impl='simclrv2'):
    with tf.name_scope('distort_color'):
        def apply_transform(i, x, brightness, contrast, saturation, hue):
            if brightness != 0 and i == 0:
                x = random_brightness(x, max_delta=brightness, impl=impl)
            elif contrast != 0 and i == 1:
                x = tf.image.random_contrast(x, lower=1-contrast, upper=1+contrast)
            elif saturation != 0 and i == 2:
                x = tf.image.random_saturation(x, lower=1-saturation, upper=1+saturation)
            elif hue != 0:
                x = tf.image.random_hue(x, max_delta=hue)
            return x

        for i in range(4):
            image = apply_transform(i, image, brightness, contrast, saturation, hue)
            image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0., 1.)
        return image
    
    
# Image RGB to Grayscale.
def to_grayscale(image, keep_channels=True):
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
    if keep_channels:
        image = tf.tile(image, [1, 1, 3])
    return image

# Color transformation on image.
def random_color_jitter(image, p=1.0, impl='simclrv2'):
    def transformation(image):
        color_jitter_t = functools.partial(color_jitter, strength=0.5, impl=impl)
        image = random_apply(color_jitter_t, p=0.8, x=image)
        return random_apply(to_grayscale, p=0.2, x=image)
    return random_apply(transformation, p=p, x=image)

# Color transformation on image.
def random_color_jitter_1p0(image, p=1.0, impl='simclrv2'):
    def transformation(image):
        color_jitter_t = functools.partial(color_jitter, strength=1.0, impl=impl)
        image = random_apply(color_jitter_t, p=0.8, x=image)
        return random_apply(to_grayscale, p=0.2, x=image)
    return random_apply(transformation, p=p, x=image)


############### SPATIAL: Cropping and Resizing ############### 

# Crop.
def distorted_bounding_box_crop(image, bbox, min_object_covered=0.1, aspect_ratio_range=(0.75, 1.33), area_range=(0.05, 1.0), max_attempts=100, scope=None):
    with tf.name_scope('distorted_bounding_box_crop'):
        shape = tf.shape(image)
        sample_distorted_bounding_box = tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box(shape, bounding_boxes=bbox, min_object_covered=min_object_covered, aspect_ratio_range=aspect_ratio_range,
                                                                           area_range=area_range, max_attempts=max_attempts, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=True)
        bbox_begin, bbox_size, _ = sample_distorted_bounding_box

        # Crop the image to the specified bounding box.
        offset_y, offset_x, _ = tf.unstack(bbox_begin)
        target_height, target_width, _ = tf.unstack(bbox_size)
        image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, offset_y, offset_x, target_height, target_width)

        return image

# Crop and resize image.
def crop_and_resize(image, height, width, area_range):
    bbox = tf.constant([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 4])
    aspect_ratio = width / height
    image = distorted_bounding_box_crop(image, bbox, min_object_covered=0.1, aspect_ratio_range=(3./4*aspect_ratio, 4./3.*aspect_ratio), area_range=area_range, max_attempts=100, scope=None)
    return tf.image.resize([image], [height, width])[0]

# Random crop and resize.
def random_crop_and_resize(image, prob=1.0):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    print('#_#', image.shape)
    def transformation(image):
        images = crop_and_resize(image=image, height=height, width=width, area_range=(0.08, 1.0))
        return images

    return random_apply(func=transformation, p=prob, x=image)


def random_crop_and_resize_p075(image, prob=1.0):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    print('#_#', image.shape)
    def transformation(image):
        images = crop_and_resize(image=image, height=height, width=width, area_range=(0.75, 1.0))
        return images

    return random_apply(func=transformation, p=prob, x=image)


# Random crop and resize SwAV Global view.
def random_crop_and_resize_global(image, prob=1.0):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    def transformation(image):
        images = crop_and_resize(image=image, height=height, width=width, area_range=(0.14, 1.0))
        return images
    return random_apply(func=transformation, p=prob, x=image)

# Random crop and resize SwAV Local view.
def random_crop_and_resize_local(image, prob=1.0):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    def transformation(image):
        images = crop_and_resize(image=image, height=height, width=width, area_range=(0.05, 0.14))
        return images
    return random_apply(func=transformation, p=prob, x=image)

############### SPATIAL: Rotation and Flipping ############### 

def random_rotate(image, p=0.5):
    return random_apply(tf.image.rot90, p, image)

def random_flip(image):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    return image


############### BLUR ############### 

def gaussian_blur(image, kernel_size, sigma, padding='SAME'):
    radius = tf.int32(kernel_size / 2)
    kernel_size = radius * 2 + 1
    x = tf.float32(tf.range(-radius, radius + 1))
    blur_filter = tf.exp(-tf.pow(x, 2.0) / (2.0 * tf.pow(tf.float32(sigma), 2.0)))
    blur_filter /= tf.reduce_sum(blur_filter)
    
    # One vertical and one horizontal filter.
    blur_v = tf.reshape(blur_filter, [kernel_size, 1, 1, 1])
    blur_h = tf.reshape(blur_filter, [1, kernel_size, 1, 1])
    num_channels = tf.shape(image)[-1]
    blur_h = tf.tile(blur_h, [1, 1, num_channels, 1])
    blur_v = tf.tile(blur_v, [1, 1, num_channels, 1])
    expand_batch_dim = image.shape.ndims == 3
    if expand_batch_dim:
        # Tensorflow requires batched input to convolutions, which we can fake with
        # an extra dimension.
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    blurred = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(image,   blur_h, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding)
    blurred = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(blurred, blur_v, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding)
    if expand_batch_dim:
        blurred = tf.squeeze(blurred, axis=0)
    return blurred

def random_blur(image, p=0.5):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    del width
    def _transform(image):
        sigma = tf.random.uniform([], 0.1, 2.0, dtype=tf.float32)
        return gaussian_blur(image, kernel_size=height//10, sigma=sigma, padding='SAME')
    return random_apply(_transform, p=p, x=image)


############### GAUSSIAN NOISE ############### 

# Adds gaussian noise to an image.
def add_gaussian_noise(image):
    # image must be scaled in [0, 1]
    with tf.name_scope('Add_gaussian_noise'):
        noise = tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape(image), mean=0.0, stddev=(50)/(255), dtype=tf.float32)
        noise_img = image + noise
        noise_img = tf.clip_by_value(noise_img, 0.0, 1.0)
    return noise_img

# Adds gaussian noise randomly to image.
def random_gaussian_noise(image, p=0.5):
    return random_apply(add_gaussian_noise, p, image)


############### SOBEL FILTER ############### 

def random_apply_sobel(func, p, x):
    return tf.cond(tf.less(tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(p, tf.float32)), lambda: tf.reduce_mean(func(x), axis=-1), lambda: x)

def random_sobel_filter(image, p=0.5):
    height, width, channels = image.shape.as_list()
    image = tf.reshape(image, (1, height, width, channels))
    applied = random_apply_sobel(tf.image.sobel_edges, p, image)
    applied = tf.reduce_mean(applied, axis=0)
    return applied


#DATA AUG WRAPPER ############### 
def data_augmentation(images, crop, rotation, flip, g_blur, g_noise, color_distort, sobel_filter, img_size, num_channels):
    images_trans = images
    # Spatial transformations.
    if crop:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_crop_and_resize, images_trans)
    if rotation:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_rotate, images_trans)
    if flip:
        images_trans = random_flip(images_trans)
    # Gaussian blur and noise transformations.    
    if g_blur:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_blur, images_trans)
    if g_noise:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_gaussian_noise, images_trans)
    # Color distorsions. 
    if color_distort:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_color_jitter, images_trans)         
    # Sobel filter.
    if sobel_filter:
        images_trans = tf.map_fn(random_sobel_filter, images_trans)
    # Make sure the image batch is in the right format.
    images_trans = tf.reshape(images_trans, [-1, img_size, img_size, num_channels])
    images_trans = tf.clip_by_value(images_trans, 0., 1.)
    
    return images_trans


`~~~

as for the command i run in the terminal:

python run_representationspathology.py --img_size 512 --batch_size 25 --epochs 60 --z_dim 128 --model BarlowTwins_3 --dataset TB --check_every 10 --report

the data feed_dict has the following form:
~~~ python 
{<tf.Tensor 'real_images_1:0' shape=(None, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>: array(...)}
{<tf.Tensor 'real_images_2:0' shape=(None, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>: array(...)}

None the less i get the following error:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_representationspathology.py", line 99, in <module>
    losses = contrast_pathology.train(epochs, data_out_path, data, restore, print_epochs=10, n_images=25, checkpoint_every=check_every, report=report)  
  File "...\Histomorphological-Phenotype-Learning\models\selfsupervised\BarlowTwins.py", line 364, in train
    transformed_images = session.run(output_layers_transformed, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options)
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\Histomorphological-Phenotype-Learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 969, in run  
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\Histomorphological-Phenotype-Learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1162, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I have tried to solve the issue and I have found that this error message arises when the data shape inside the array is not the same. Nonetheless, checking the data shape shows otherwise and I can't figure out the source of the issue.

train tries to convert its inputs to numeric arrays.  subfeed_val is the local name of one of those inputs; without looking at tensorflow code I can't say which.  One way to debug this is to examine each of the inputs, checking for numpy array attributes like shape and dtype.  If not arrays, try np.asarray(arg, dtype=float) till you reproduce this error.
